# how to display gallery videos one page

Tags: javascript, video, show-hide, display

I'm facing problem in showing videos in my web page to show movie

How to show a video in the first display

And how to make one video plays and  no other videos playing in the background
To show one video in the first offer and play Video and one in the background
Any one help me..Thanks a lot in advance..

I tried this....
I do not have a lot of experience in JavaScript

code javascript

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
// configurable but likely overkill
var PANELS = new Array("pn_1", "pn_2", "pn_3", "pn_4", "pn_5");
// toggle to one of our panels
function togglePanel (pnl) {
    for (var p=0; p < PANELS.length; p++)        
    {
        document.getElementById(PANELS[p]).style.display = 
             (PANELS[p] == pnl) ? "block" : "none";
        }
    }

//-->
</script>
```

code style and html

```
<!--start style-->
<style type="text/css">



.dispPanel {
    width: 100%;
    height: 480px;

}

a:link, a:visited {
    color: #f5f5f5;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
}
.bot {
  background-color: #0af; 
    border: 1px solid green;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
}

.bot:hover {
    background-color: #666;
}
</style>

<!--end style-->


<!--start table-->
<table dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><a class="bot" href="javascript:togglePanel(PANELS[0])"><b>Server 1</b></a></td>
<td><a class="bot" href="javascript:togglePanel(PANELS[1])"><b>Server 2</b></a></td>
<td><a class="bot" href="javascript:togglePanel(PANELS[2])"><b>Server 3</b></a></td>
<td><a class="bot" href="javascript:togglePanel(PANELS[3])"><b>Server 4</b></a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<div class="dispPanel" id="pn_1">
<b>openload</b><br />
<iframe allowfullscreen="true" frameborder="0" height="430" mozallowfullscreen="true" scrolling="no" src="https://openload.co/embed/1OBh3Ks0A4U/CimaClub.Com.One_Piece_767_%5BHD%5D.mp4" webkitallowfullscreen="true" width="100%"></iframe></div>
<div class="dispPanel" id="pn_2">
<b>ok.ru</b><br />
<iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="430" src="//ok.ru/videoembed/205259279081" width="100%"></iframe></div>
<div class="dispPanel" id="pn_3">
<b>vidhos</b><br />
<iframe frameborder="0" height="360" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="NO" src="http://vidhos.com/embed-sovtd12lco81-640x360.html" width="640"></iframe></div>
<div class="dispPanel" id="pn_4">
<b>nowvideo</b><br />
<iframe frameborder="0" height="430" scrolling="no" src="//www.nowvideo.sx/embed/?v=3b888d66981dd" width="100%"></iframe><br />
```